# NSView - under what conditions may the bounds and frame *size* be inequal?

Tags: cocoa, nsview

I know that frame is a view's frame relative to it's parent, and bounds is the view's internal bounds (with origin always [0, 0] except in the case of scroll views?).

However, I'm unclear under what conditions the frame and bounds **size** may differ, if at all. Is there official Apple documentation stating whether `frame.size = bounds.size` or `frame.size ?= bounds.size`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do whatever you want with the bounds. Imagine that your view is a painting, which you can only view through a camera. Moving the origin will change the portion of the painting which you can currently see by moving the camera around. Shrinking the size zooms in, so that less of the painting is visible, but it appears larger. Expanding the size zooms out, so that more of the painting is visible, but it appears smaller.

From the [documentation for `bounds`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/bounds):

> By default, the origin of the returned rectangle is (0, 0) and its size matches the size of the receiver’s frame rectangle (measured in points)....
>
> If you explicitly change the origin or size of the bounds rectangle, this method does not return the default rectangle and instead returns the rectangle you set. If you add a rotation factor to the view, however, that factor is also reflected in the returned bounds rectangle.

And from the [documentation for `setBounds:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSView_Class/Reference/NSView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSView/setBounds%3a):

> The bounds rectangle determines the origin and scale of the receiver’s coordinate system within its frame rectangle....
>
> After calling this method, NSView creates an internal transform (or appends these changes to an existing internal transform) to convert from frame coordinates to bounds coordinates in your view. As long as the width-to-height ratio of the two coordinate systems remains the same, your content appears normal. If the ratios differ, your content may appear skewed.